# cakephp3のページネーションで表示するページを指定したい

Tags: php, cakephp

cakephp初心者です。
cakephpのページネーションで表示するページを指定することは可能でしょうか。

以下のような処理を考えています。

１．ページネーションのある一覧フォームを表示。
２．一覧フォームから選択したレコードの詳細フォームを表示。
３．詳細フォームでレコードを更新し、一覧フォームへ戻る。
４．一覧フォームを２の状態の時のページで表示する。

コントローラ側でページネーションのページを指定することは出来ないでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 試してないのですがコントローラーのpaginate初期設定でpage:2とすれば出来ますかね。

Answer (score 1):

> cakephpのページネーションで表示するページを指定することは可能でしょうか。

この質問に対しての回答は「はい」です。

今回の例で行けば、

> ３．詳細フォームでレコードを更新し、一覧フォームへ戻る。

の時のアクションメソッド内で、処理の完了時に行うリダイレクト先指定で、

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index', '?' => ['page' => 2]]);
```

のようにして、ページ指定可能です。

---

ただし、ここで「どのページに戻るのか」を知る必要があります。indexアクションに検索などの機能を設けていた場合は、その検索オプションも引き継いで戻りたいですよね。

そのためには、

> １．ページネーションのある一覧フォームを表示。

のindexアクションで、セッションにクエリパラメーターを保存しておき、3のリダイレクト時に取り出すというやり方があります。

```
public function index() // 一覧
{
    // ...
    $this->request->session()
        ->write('ControllerName.index.query', $this->request->getQuery()); // セッションキー名は適宜変更
}

public function edit()  // 詳細フォーム
{
    // ...
    if (/* ... */) {
        // 処理が正常完了したときのリダイレクト
        return $this->redirect([
            'action' => 'index',
            '?' => $this->request->session()
                    ->consume('ControllerName.index.query'), // consumeで読み込みと削除
        ]);
    }
    // ...
}
```

この手法の場合、複数のタブなどで別々の表示条件のindexを開いていた場合は、セッションに状態を保持している都合上、最後に開いたindexの表示条件で戻ることになりますので、その点だけ留意してください。

Comment: 詳細な説明ありがとうございます。pageプロパティに設定するよりもredirectで行った方がcakeらしいですね。こちらの方法で実装してみます。また複数タブでのセッションの問題は考慮してませんでした。非常に参考になりました。ありがとうございました。